# unable to map as url is not an array // React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi I have a main page called FeaturedProduct.js which lists all the products fetch from the API https://fakestoreapi.com.

I trying to set up react router dom version (6) whereby user click on any of the product will open up that single product through Product.js

This is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-smoke-r7yik9?file=/src/Product.js

I having issues because I can't use the map function without errors.
The error being `data.map' is a not a function (in Product.js)

Do I need to access further into the "api" json like data.x.map?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why are you trying to _map_ over something that's not an array. `data` is an object so just directly access its properties... `data.title`, `data.price`, etc. Why is it that everyone who posts about the [FakeStoreAPI](https://fakestoreapi.com/) here never checks the [response format](https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1)?

Comment: The response data is an object, not an array. There's nothing to map over, just access the properties you need from the `data` state. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: please take a read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: sorry, I understand, I will improve and put more research effort into it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Always check carefully the response you are getting from an api weather its object or an array.

i have modified your file, you can replace it with your original product.js component.

And always use ?. operator whenever you play with data that come from an api because useEffect hook will run after your component is loaded, hence it will give you an error that your data is undefined. It will not happen in your case you are getting only single object which is fast operation, but if you are getting larger data then you have to use ?. operator.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// individual product
// functional component

const Product = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(''); 
  const { id } = useParams();  

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`) // change from ?id=${id} to ${id} because API url is .com/products/1  // But couldn't map due to not being array
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);        
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>              
          <div className="product-container" key={data?.id}>
            <div>
              <img className="prod-image" src={data?.image} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1 className="brand">{data?.title}</h1>
              <h2>{data?.category}</h2>
              <p>{data?.description}</p>
              <p>
                <strong>Price:</strong> {data?.price}
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Rating:</strong> {data?.rating?.rate}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>          
      <div className="back">
        <Link to="/">Feature Products</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: so the optional chaining will result a "undefined" rather than error right

Comment: how do you console.log to get the properties of selected id?

Comment: i did not understand your question, do you want to console your data or do you want to console your product id from url